# Why mysql varchar column appended .0 to phonenumer when we insert with python pandas

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

A table created with multiple columns with 5 phone number columns, all of them has data type like

```
varchar(15)
```

But when I insert phone number of 10 digits without - or () like 9999999999 then in phonenumber3,phonenumber4,phonenumber5 columns alone get updated as **9999999999.0**

I'm reading from CSV and writing into table using pandas **to_sql()**.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Might be due to missing data, e.g. `NaN` which downcasts the column to float. Try to read CSV with `dtype={'phone_col_name':str}`.

Comment: @ Quang Hoang No. If I insert same number to all 5 columns then column 1 and 2 updated fine. This 3,4 and 5 alone updated with .0
This might be any charset issue?

Comment: MySQL will not add anything. It stores strictly the value provided by the client.

Comment: @ Quang Hoang Reading CSV with dtype={'phone_col_name':str} worked well!

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV data is generated from server (unaltered by user),  "zero" data is preserved in importing. Assuming " quotes as container. Everything should be fine.

If the CSV data is altered by the user such as, editing/saving...  The "zero" data will be trimmed, as the software editor like excel or libre office will omit the "zero" during saving. Work-around with this is to edit the CSV file in Text Editor (e.g. Sublime)  the columns should be preserved as "012345678"  with the quotes as container.